# Computer is looking for a blue tooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

While i have never worrried about security risks, and I don't fully shut down my computer every night, I am thinking maybe I should be more cautious.  I am concerned about a recent problem. I do not use a bluetooth keyboard, but when I open my computer in the mornings recently, it has taken a long time to get going, saying it is looking for a blue tooth computer keyboard.  Could this be a type of hacking?  What can I do about it? Could it be a neighbor?  Is there a program to reveal there has been a security problem?  Thank you,

Worried

Comment: what operating system are you using? that could narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes, what OS and what sort of antivirus programs you have running would be a good start. Is your firewall up? Also, Anything else out of the ordinary besides that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure there is no Spyware on your computer, download Malwarebyte's Antimalware and perform a scan:  [Download MBAM here](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download)

Do you see any bluetooth devices when you follow these steps?

Open Devices and Printers by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then, on the Start menu, clicking Devices and Printers.

If there is any device paired, you should be able to remove it here.